# schema.rb file is empty after I run rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

the summary of the problem: I'm trying to create a simple crud project to practice and when I create a table using `rails g migration create_articles` it creates a migration file. So when I add the code

```
`create_table :articles do |t|
 t.string :title
 t.text :description
 t.timestamps
end`
```

then run the rails command `rails db:migrate` a schema file is created, but it is completely empty.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_08_21_180236) do
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I have

- deleted and re-downloaded everything multiple times using a script found on rubyonmac.com
- I've tried dropping the empty table by generating another migration file and when that gets pushed to the db nothing happens and the table remains
- use `rails db:rollback` and that works but when I rerun the migration file the problem persists

like I said in the beginning of the post I'm using a script I found to setup my MacBook Pro easily so I'm not sure where this problem is coming from. thanks in advance for any help.

edit: also the problem persists across new projects created with command `rails new blog` or using `rails g scaffold Articles` to create the migrate files then migrate.

Comment: The timestamps seem to be generating fine. Have you tried using `t.column :title, :string` and `t.column :description, :text` to create the other columns?

Comment: I found a solution using bin/rails generate model Article title:string body:text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bin/rails generate model Article title:string body:text
```

this code worked for me. I found if I add the columns when generating the migration file in the terminal the file migrates perfectly and the two columns are created. however if I generate a migration file and then go into the file itself in VSCode to make changes before running `rails db:migrate` it sometimes worked but mostly didn't.